# print json value which have php array value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

```
{"success":"","error":"<span style='color: red;' id='inin'><p>The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.<\/p><p>The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.<\/p><\/span>",**"file":["asdf.PNG,","asdfgvb.PNG,"]**}
```

How to print the JSON file value in JavaScript alert

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch the response from xhr, JSON.Parse and then you can use it as object. Like object.error in a alert or something.

So in most easy solution:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"success":"","error":"<span style='color: red;' id='inin'><p>The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.<\/p><p>The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.<\/p><\/span>","file":["asdf.PNG,","asdfgvb.PNG,"]}');

var d1 = document.getElementById('div');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', obj.error);
```

Comment: Mark it as answer if it answers your question please. So people find quick answers